# Mysql crashed and not starting in xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

Here my log files in mysql

2019-12-10 15:10:18 1428 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
    2019-12-10 15:10:18 5160 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

```
2019-12-10 15:10:18 5160 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2019-12-10 15:10:18 5160 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2019-12-10 15:10:18 5160 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-12-10 15:10:18 5160 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2019-12-10 15:10:18 5160 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-12-10 15:10:18 5160 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2019-12-10 15:10:18 5160 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2019-12-10 15:10:18 5160 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-12-10 15:10:18 5160 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-12-10 15:10:18 5160 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=7472761787
2019-12-10 15:10:19 5160 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 2850 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is 1963520
2019-12-10 15:10:19 5160 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 307 pages from redo log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deleting ibdata1 file , ib_logfile1, ib_logfile1 from c:xampp\mysql\data directory , it started working

Answer (score 0):

Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.

According to
https://blogs.oracle.com/supportingmysql/entry/remove_on_sight_thread_concurrency
, MySQL 5.6 will deprecated three parameters in the configuration file:

thread_concurrency
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size
innodb_use_sys_malloc

Solution:
If you are currently using version 5.1 or 5.5, it is recommended to set the parameter value to 1
innodb_use_sys_malloc = 1
If version 5.6.3 or later, comment the parameter:
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size

Comment: In which file  can you describe it briefly

Comment: in your MySQL configuration file, if you are using windows visit https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/sqlquerychat/sql-help/others/location-of-mysql-configuration-file-my-cnf-or-my-ini-on-windows-querychat/